# GvrVideoPlayerTexture is "not ready to Play!"

Tags: android, video, google-vr, daydream, google-vr-sdk

I think I've done everything right. I've followed all the instructions and tutorials out there pretty closely. Alas, I can not get video to play when using GvrVideoPlayerTexture.

I get the following error message: 
Video player not ready to Play!

> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   GvrVideoPlayerTexture:play() (at Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/Video/GvrVideoPlayerTexture.cs:513)
>   GVRSample.AutoPlayVideo:Update() (at Assets/GoogleVR/Demos/Scripts/VideoDemo/AutoPlayVideo.cs:62)

Here's what I have done:

Created New Project

Imported Assets > Import Package > Custom Package: GoogleVRForUnity.unitypackage

Imported Assets > Import Package > Custom Package: InstantPreviewForGVRUnity....unitypackage

Build Settings > Platform: Android > Switch Platform

Player Settings: checked VR Support, choose Daydream, API Level 7.0

To my scene I added: various systems (GvrControllerMain, GvrEditorEmulator, GvrEventSystem).

Created environment game objects (a ground, some walls - inspired by the Roll a Ball tutorial), a player prefab I’ve made with Camera, pointer and walk script

Imported Assets > Import Package > Custom Package:...\Assets\GoogleVR\GVRVideoPlayer.unitypackage

Created a Quad

Added the GvrVideoPlayerTexture script, with Buffer size: 4, Video Type: Other, Video URL: jar:file://${Application.dataPath}!/assets/vid_bigbuckbunny.mp4

Added the AutoPlayVideo script

Pressed play.

And then... no video. I can move my player around, I can look around. The instant preview works fine. But no video playback.

If I disable GvrVideoPlayerTexture, and add the Unity Video Player script, playback without audio will happen. I really need audio.

Here is a screen cap of my current set up:

[image: Here is a screen cap of my current set up.]

**So, what might I be able to do to fix it?**

(also, maybe a different question for a different thread, but what's the benefit of GvrVideoPlayerTexture vs. Unity's built in Video Player?)

Answer (score 1):

The GvrVideoPlayerTexture only works on Android devices, not in Editor.

The benefit of the GvrVideoPlayerTexture player for a time was that it was the only free video player for Android.  GvrVideoPlayerTexture still maintains advantages over Unity's player of supporting adaptive streaming formats HLS and Dash and will soon support head-tracked ambisonic audio rendering.